# k3d how to see imported images

Tags: kubernetes, k3d

I have following issue,
I'm using kubernetes as k3d, when I apply new pods I need to import docker image for it,
How can I check which images are imported to k3d ? When I was checking - I see only option to import image.

Answer (score 1):

There is not dedicated command to do it, but there is one way to achieve this

When you create k3d cluster with name `mycluster`

```bash
k3d cluster create mycluster --servers 1 --agents 1
```

You have to get running containers using `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                             NAMES
30d444e398b3   ghcr.io/k3d-io/k3d-proxy:5.6.0   "/bin/sh -c nginx-pr…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:43607->6443/tcp   k3d-mycluster-serverlb
ab845e460925   rancher/k3s:v1.27.4-k3s1         "/bin/k3s agent"         3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes                                     k3d-mycluster-agent-0
f83045d927c7   rancher/k3s:v1.27.4-k3s1         "/bin/k3s server --t…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes                                     k3d-mycluster-server-0
```

Then take any `server` or `agent` node you want to check, I took `k3d-mycluster-server-0`, and running command below will give you all images on that node

```bash
docker exec k3d-mycluster-server-0 crictl images
```

You should get clear output

```
IMAGE                                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
docker.io/library/nginx                      alpine              529b5644c430c       44.4MB
docker.io/library/nginx                      latest              a8758716bb6aa       191MB
docker.io/rancher/klipper-lb                 v0.4.4              af74bd845c4a8       4.92MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-library-traefik   2.9.10              d1e26b5f8193d       39.6MB
docker.io/rancher/mirrored-pause             3.6                 6270bb605e12e       301kB
```

In my case I already imported 2 nginx images, rest are images required to run cluster node

If you want to grab all images across nodes you can run (some of them may exist only on one node) and it requires `jq` installed

```bash
for x in $(docker ps --format json | jq ".Names" -r | grep -e '-server-' -e '-agent-'); do docker exec $x crictl images --output json | jq ".images[].repoTags[0]" -r; done | sort -u
```